# npm material-ui-table-edit loader

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, material-ui

I have a ReactJS project and I need to use and edit table. I found this one interesting:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-table-edit

I did npm i material-ui-table-edit --save

this is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "app-2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --watch --watch-poll --config webpack.dev.config.js --colors --content-base ./client  --history-api-fallback",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint src"
  },
  "author": "",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "alt": "^0.18.4",
    "alt-container": "^1.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.11.0",
    "formsy-material-ui": "^0.4.3",
    "formsy-react": "^0.18.0",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.15.0",
    "material-ui-table-edit": "^2.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-cookie": "^0.4.6",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2",
    "react-motion": "^0.4.3",
    "react-router": "=2.5.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "uuid": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-jest": "^12.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "jest-cli": "^12.0.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack-plugin-notifier": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

My webpack.dev.config.js:

```
  output: {
    path: './client',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].bundle.js'
  },
  debug: true,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ProgressBarPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.bundle.js'),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules']
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {test: /\.jsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'eslint'}
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'react-hot!babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json?$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.less/,
        loader: 'style!css!less'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css!postcss'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'file?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=./src'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I am getting this error when I import it:

```
import EditTable from 'material-ui-table-edit';
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/material-ui-table-edit/index.jsx
Module parse failed: C:\Users\karim.eltal\Documents\workspace\cgbs-attributes\web-entry\node_modules\material-ui-table-edit\index.jsx Unexpected token (68:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (68:13)
```

Comment: do you have a JSX loader configured for Babble?

Comment: @Kosch isn't that enough ?   test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'react-hot!babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** It's possible to consume `material-ui-table-edit` out of the box now. Thanks to @mk. for the fix!

I left the old answer below for reference since sometimes you need to patch it up like this.

---

By the looks of it the author of the package doesn't provide it in a precompiled form. This means if you want to use it, you'll need to compile it yourself. You can achieve this with an `include`:

```
var path = require('path');    

...

{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loader: 'react-hot!babel',
  include: path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules', 'material-ui-table-edit'),  
  exclude: /node_modules/
},
```

That will make your Babel setup pick it up.

Or, as David mentioned, you could consider some other alternative or poke the original author about it to see if he is willing to publish a compiled version.

Comment: Do you have an alternative in mind? I was looking for a table that would have the ability to add/delete row dynamically but I was not lucky so far. If you have nothing in mind do you think I could use the material-ui table and render a new row on a button click?

Comment: I developed [a little component](http://reactabular.js.org) for this purpose myself. [Griddle](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle) and [FixedDataTable](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/) seem like the most popular options at the moment.

Comment: include: path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules', 'material-ui-table-edit'),
                 ^

ReferenceError: path is not defined

Comment: You'll need `var path = require('path');` or equivalent given it relies on that Node module.

Comment: ERROR in ./src/scripts/index.jsx
Module parse failed: C:\Users\karim\Documents\workspace\cgbs-attributes\web-entry\node_modules\eslint-loader\index.js!C:\Users\karim\Documents\workspace\cgbs-attributes\web-entry\src\scripts\index.jsx Unexpected token (15:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: By the way I experimented with Griddle. It is a cool grid but it has not the functionality that I want. I tried to change the rows data after an event but the rows simply do not change after the rows data changes from the store. The grid that I want is an interactive grid and not a static one.

Comment: Did you put the `include` to the `loaders` section? Why are you passing it through eslint?

Comment: Hard to say what's going on. I would contact the author or fork and repackage myself.

Comment: I already did, he promised the compiled version soon. Let's hope so :)

Comment: published the compiled version in `material-ui-table-edit@3.0.0`.

Comment: @mk. Cool to hear! I'll amend the answer then.

Answer (score -1):

Their library has `jsx` in it (bad), your loader is (rightly) skipping `node_modules` so it's not running their code through babel because it's in node_modules.

You will need to include their library in your loader config.

OR...

My two cents: if a package author ships code that requires transpilation, they don't know what they're doing. Couple that with 6 github stars and I'd pick another package.

Comment: Do you have an alternative in mind? I was looking for a table that would have the ability to add/delete row dynamically but I was not lucky so far. If you have nothing in mind do you think I could use the material-ui table and render a new row on a button click?

Comment: This is relatively easy to do yourself, it's the sort of thing React is great at. I'd suggest always giving it a go yourself first, you'd be amazed how easy some stuff is.

Comment: The grid that I want is a dynamic grid. I do not want that will simply show the data. The user should do changes add/remove rows and then submit. It is basically the component in question. Any idea if there is something out there and if not how can I connect my grid to the data in the state?